# jQuery: Append once and stop (worked in older versions)

Tags: jquery, append, appendto

So here's the code I'm using:

```
$(function(){
    $('<div id="info" style="width:auto; height:auto;"/>').load('test.php?var='+d+' #se', function() {
        $('#main').append(this);
    });
});
}
```

Now, when I trigger the function (with a keyup in a input box) the div loaded is appended over and over again on every keyup event.

I'm using jQuery 1.5 - in older versions, namely 1.2.6, the div wasn't appended after the first time and it worked fine (bug?).

How do I prevent the div from being appended over and over again? (disabling the "trigger" is not an option unfortunately.) I also tried appendTo, which is pretty much the same problem.

Someone help me please! Thanks a lot

Comment: Just wrap the load call in a conditional checking to see if `div#info` already exists.

Comment: You can add data to your main div to check if the div is already loaded and just do nothing in that event.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you can use [`.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to bind your keyup handler:

```
$('whatever').one('keyup', function() {
    $('<div id="info" style="width:auto; height:auto;"/>').load('test.php?var='+d+' #se', function() {
        $('#main').append(this);
    });
});
```

The `.one` function acts just like [`.bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) except that it unbinds itself after it executes once.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$(function(){
   if($("#info").length==0)
   {
      $('<div id="info" style="width:auto; height:auto;"/>').load('test.php?var='+d+' #se', function() {
        $('#main').append(this);
      });
   }
});
}
```

Assuming that "#info" is added dynamically.

Comment: This would never complete. Do you mean `length==0`?